# Why is the query operator 'ElementAt' is not supported in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, extension-methods

In LINQ to SQL, I get the exception "*The query operator 'ElementAt' is not supported.*" When trying to use the ElementAt extension method on an IQueryable returned from a LINQ to SQL query.

Here is the stack trace:

```
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression node)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.ElementAt[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Int32 index)
```

Now I realize to get rid of this exception and to use ElementAt I could call '.ToList()' before using the extension method and it will work. That is fine, but I still don't like the fact that this is a runtime exception (and what seems like LSP violation).

Is there a reason why these methods cannot be supported? Is it just because they cannot be translated easily into SQL? What other IQueryable/IEnumerable extension methods are not supported, is there a list somewhere?

It would be nice to avoid runtime exceptions.

Comment: No idea why they haven't implemented it, but you're much better off using .Skip(n - 1).FirstOrDefault() rather than .ToList(), as those concepts will translate to a SQL query rather than requiring the entire result set to be loaded on the local machine

Comment: Yeah I think I will be using Skip(n - 1).FirstOrDefault() rather than .ToList(), thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From MSDN, [Standard Query Operator Translation (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx) - this article contains the full list of operators that haven't been translated:

- TakeWhile , SkipWhile
- Reverse
- Last , LastOrDefault
- ElementAt , ElementAtOrDefault
- DefaultIfEmpty

> Operators with No Translation
>
> The following methods are not
> translated by LINQ to SQL. The most
> common reason is the difference
> between unordered multisets and
> sequences.
>
> Operators
>
> Rationale
>
> ...
>
> **ElementAt** ,
> ElementAtOrDefault
>
> SQL queries operate on multisets, not
> on indexable sequences.

Comment: Hmm... interesting, I suppose that kind of makes sense. Skip(n).First() is much more representative of whats actually going on... Similar to why I always kind of hated having the .Count() extension on IEnumerable<T> (don't mind it on IQueryable, but I don't think it should be there on IEnumerable)

Answer (score 11):

It is odd, in particular because `Skip()` is supported. Could you, for example, do:

```
var obj = source.Skip(index).First();
```

?

Comment: Yeah I tried using '.Skip(index).First()', works fine, I've also used '.Count()' no problem

Comment: FYI, I had to use OrderBy() before Skip

Comment: And suppose you want to get a specific element of a table, how would you do?