# Random selection of query result Linq

Tags: c#, linq, random

i have a query which will result 10 or 20 or any number number of rows. Below is the query.

```
   var q = (from c in session.DB.Question where c.Level='1' && c.Group='1' select c);
```

This query can give me any number of rows.

But i have to show just 1 row from the result. I can select top 1/first but i would like select randomly.

i saw a topic about this: [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)
but i want it in LinQ

Please help me how to get random row from the result.

Comment: Technically, `First()` without a sort will get you an 'random' row ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF Code First: How to get random rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781893/ef-code-first-how-to-get-random-rows)

Comment: Do you have any identity keys from your questionnaires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort items by [random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487168(v=vs.110).aspx) value and select first:

```
var q = (from c in session.DB.Question 
         where c.Level =='1' && c.Group =='1' 
         select c)
        .OrderBy(o => SqlFunctions.Rand())
        .First();
```

Comment: thanks, whats the namespacec for sqlFunction.Rand() ?

Comment: If you've added the reference, then `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487168(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AlexR. em, it's the same link i posted in answer

Comment: i've added     "using system.data.sqlcliet" but still sqlFunctions.Rand() is unknown.

Comment: @Backs "the name 'sqlfunctions ' does not exist in the current context "

Comment: @Ali Project -> Add Reference... -> check `System.Data.Entity` -> OK

Comment: ok thanks, it is working. but i use NewGuide a few hours ago and sent it as answer.

Comment: @Ali `NewGuid` is slower than `SqlFunctions.Rand`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all. i found it and working:

```
        var q = (from c in Session.DB.WinQuestionSet
                 where c.Level == "easy" && c.Grade == "1"
                 select c).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1).Single();
        label1.Text = q.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your questions has an Id. Please see example below. I used Random class to generate random number.

```
        List<Question> questions = new List<Question>
        {
            new Question { Id = 10, Name = "What?" },
            new Question { Id = 12, Name = "How?" },
            new Question { Id = 32, Name = "When?" },
            new Question { Id = 41, Name = "Where?" },
        };
        var q = (from c in questions select c);

        int i = 1;
        Dictionary<int, int> questionKeys = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach (var item in questions)
        {
            questionKeys.Add(i, item.Id);
            i++;
        }

        Random rdm = new Random();
        int randomRow = rdm.Next(1, q.Count());

        var questionId = questionKeys.Where(x => x.Key == randomRow).Select(x => x.Value).Single();

        var result = q.Where(x => x.Id == questionId).Single();

        Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
```

Comment: tnx, But maybe the numbers are not in sequence, so int randomRow = rdm.Next(1, q.Count()); may not contains ID in result

Comment: what if Id is not sequence from 1 to `Count`?

Comment: @Backs         yes,exactly

Comment: Put your collection or the not sequence id to a dictionary<int, int> and populate the key as sequence then use the random number

Comment: as you can see, author need a LinqToSQL solution. so, using dictionaries can be a bad one, when you suddenly get 1mln rows instead of 10-20

Comment: yes. 1 million questions is very bad :). my solution only can accommodate only few hundreds. Well done mate.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `data` is your data rows:

```
Random rand = new Random();
var row = data.ElementAt(rand.Next(data.Count));
```

Note that this does not work for Linq to SQL, and thus should be used after you query your db.

Comment: LinqToSql does not support `ElementAt` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147767/why-is-the-query-operator-elementat-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: I did not consider that, good catch. I will update my answer.